# manage date fields when are int in the db

Tags: forms, date, asp.net-mvc-2

Hi in my db there is a field "date_start" type integer.

This is the part of form for this field

```
<div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.date_start) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.date_start, new { @class = "calendar" })%>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.date_start) %>
            </div>
```

In the form i want that the field's format is date type. 
and memorize it in int type after calling a my function for the convertion.
How can i manage it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I'm assuming you have a Linq-generated class, which we'll call LGC, and in that class is a property of type int called date_start.

To start, wrap LGC in a another class:

```
public class LGCPageForm
{
   public LGC BaseModel { get; set; }
   public DateTime date_start_as_date { get; set; }
}
```

Set the LGCPageForm class to be your Page's Model class. That'll require some refactoring, but I think it's your best option. Now, in your form, you'll have something like:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.date_start_as_date) %>
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.date_start_as_date, new { @class = "calendar" })%>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.date_start_as_date) %>
</div>
```

Then, capturing your postback. You'll definitely want to implement validation via DataAnnotations, but this should get you started in the right direction:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitWeirdDate(LGCPageForm form)
{
    //I'm not sure if this is the conversion you want?
    form.LGC.date_start = form.LGC.date_start_as_date.Ticks;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's the UNIX timestamp for this, which is basically an integer (and can be stored as such). I have no clue how to implement this in ASP.NET though. Check if there's a class named TimeStamp which can take an integer upon construct (or later on), then look for a form element that takes a TimeStamp. 
That said, I haven't got any experience at all in ASP.NET.